# How to remove More help link from moodle 2.8 help popup?

Tags: moodle

I want to remove More help link from moodle 2.8 help pop up.

I am attaching screenshot:

[image: Moodle More help link screenshot]

After click on this link, open docs.moodle.org/28/en/mod/lesson/view page

Got solution from moodle forum but not working for me.its for moodle 2.7

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Any specific reason to hide this?

Comment: Yes Client requirement

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to remove the help link without modifying Moodle code. However you could either:

- Define `$CFG->docroot` in your `config.php` to customise the URLs, or
- Use CSS to hide the link.

If modifying *core* is not an issue, the easiest way is to modify the function `get_formatted_help_string` so that it never looks for the language string ending in `_link`. You would remove the following block:

```
$helplink = $identifier . '_link';
if ($sm->string_exists($helplink, $component)) {  // Link to further info in Moodle docs.
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for first option but after docroot it taking /28/en/mod/lesson/view. I mean it not completely removing or changing. And using CSS, there has dyanamic generating id  attribute of that link so not able to set display:none for that id

Comment: Basically I am interested in modifying moodle core code.Can you tell me the script name?

Comment: I added the  `core hack` option to the answer.

Comment: Thanks..Works for me.

Comment: Thanks. Could you flag the answer as selected answer?